# Remote debugging w/ docker-compose interpreter and podman: Could not connect to host.docker.internal: xxxxx (socket.gaierror: [Errno -2])

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, port, podman

When setting up a very basic dockerized python project using podman, connecting to the remote debugger fails.  It is impossible to debug, but just running it works fine.

It appears to be having trouble using the random port to host.docker.internal.

PyCharm: PyCharm 2023.3 EAP
Podman: version 4.7.0
MacOS: 14.1.2 (23B92)

Steps to recreate this:

Set up a basic dockerized python project with a simple main.py, using podman for Mac in place of docker

Define a new server to connect to "Docker for Mac" as shown here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-docker.html

Create new remote docker compose python interpreter as illustrated here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-compose-as-a-remote-interpreter.html

Create a Python Run/Debug configuration called "main" using the remote interpreter defined in step 3, specifying the script to start main.py

Select "main" as the active Run/Debug config, then select "debug"

The debug session fails with an exit code 1, showing that the container cannot reach host.docker.internal:xxxx, where "xxxx" is the port that is randomly assigned (59084 in the output below).

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
python3 \
python3-pip \
python3-dev
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "3"
services:
app:
build: .
ports:
- "9999:8080"
volumes:
- .:/usr/src/app
environment:
- VAULT_API=shashasha
```

Console output of debug window after debug session fails:

```
/usr/bin/python3 /opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiprocess --qt-support=auto --client host.docker.internal --port 59084 --file /opt/project/main.py

podman-compose version: 1.0.6

['podman', '--version', '']

using podman version: 4.7.0

** merged:

{

"version": "3",

"services": {

    "app": {

      "build": ".",

      "ports": [

        "9999:8080"

      ],

      "volumes": [

        ".:/usr/src/app",

        "/Users/cjohns153/source/remoteAttempt:/opt/project:rw",

        "pycharm_helpers_PY-233.11799.32:/opt/.pycharm_helpers"

      ],

      "environment": {

        "VAULT_API": "shashasha",

        "PYTHONPATH": "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/third_party/thriftpy:/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev:/opt/project/:/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend:/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pycharm_display:/opt/project/",

        "PYDEVD_LOAD_VALUES_ASYNC": "True",

        "PYCHARM_INTERACTIVE_PLOTS": "1",

        "PYTHONUNBUFFERED": "1",

        "PYCHARM_DISPLAY_HTTP_PROXY": "http://host.docker.internal:63342",

        "PYTHONIOENCODING": "UTF-8",

        "LIBRARY_ROOTS": "",

        "PYCHARM_HOSTED": "1",

        "PYCHARM_DISPLAY_PORT": "63342",

        "IPYTHONENABLE": "True",

        "USE_LOW_IMPACT_MONITORING": "True",

        "IDE_PROJECT_ROOTS": "/opt/project/"

      },

      "command": [

        "/usr/bin/python3",

        "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py",

        "--multiprocess",

        "--qt-support=auto",

        "--client",

        "host.docker.internal",

        "--port",

        "59084",

        "--file",

        "/opt/project/main.py"

      ],

      "stdin_open": true,

      "working_dir": "/opt/project/"

    }

},

"volumes": {

    "pycharm_helpers_PY-233.11799.32": {}

},

"_dirname": "/Users/cjohns153/source/remoteAttempt"

}

** excluding: set()

['podman', 'inspect', '-t', 'image', '-f', '{{.Id}}', 'remoteattempt_app']

['podman', 'ps', '--filter', 'label=io.podman.compose.project=remoteattempt', '-a', '--format', '{{ index .Labels "io.podman.compose.config-hash"}}']

recreating: ...

** excluding: set()

podman stop -t 10 remoteattempt_app_1

remoteattempt_app_1

exit code: 0

podman rm remoteattempt_app_1

remoteattempt_app_1

exit code: 0

recreating: done

podman volume inspect remoteattempt_pycharm_helpers_PY-233.11799.32 || podman volume create remoteattempt_pycharm_helpers_PY-233.11799.32

['podman', 'volume', 'inspect', 'remoteattempt_pycharm_helpers_PY-233.11799.32']

['podman', 'network', 'exists', 'remoteattempt_default']

podman create --name=remoteattempt_app_1 --label io.podman.compose.config-hash=daf81585befc7ae6b4c96ad9d8a75e93837bfc4eaf8afb6ed90ac5aa3bf2ce17 --label io.podman.compose.project=remoteattempt --label io.podman.compose.version=1.0.6 --label PODMAN_SYSTEMD_UNIT=podman-compose@remoteattempt.service --label com.docker.compose.project=remoteattempt --label com.docker.compose.project.working_dir=/Users/cjohns153/source/remoteAttempt --label com.docker.compose.project.config_files=/Users/cjohns153/source/remoteAttempt/docker-compose.yml,/Users/cjohns153/Library/Caches/JetBrains/PyCharm2023.3/tmp/docker_compose/docker-compose.override.7.yml --label com.docker.compose.container-number=1 --label com.docker.compose.service=app -e VAULT_API=shashasha -e PYTHONPATH=/opt/.pycharm_helpers/third_party/thriftpy:/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev:/opt/project/:/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend:/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pycharm_display:/opt/project/ -e PYDEVD_LOAD_VALUES_ASYNC=True -e PYCHARM_INTERACTIVE_PLOTS=1 -e PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 -e PYCHARM_DISPLAY_HTTP_PROXY=http://host.docker.internal:63342 -e PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 -e LIBRARY_ROOTS= -e PYCHARM_HOSTED=1 -e PYCHARM_DISPLAY_PORT=63342 -e IPYTHONENABLE=True -e USE_LOW_IMPACT_MONITORING=True -e IDE_PROJECT_ROOTS=/opt/project/ -v /Users/cjohns153/source/remoteAttempt:/usr/src/app -v /Users/cjohns153/source/remoteAttempt:/opt/project:rw -v remoteattempt_pycharm_helpers_PY-233.11799.32:/opt/.pycharm_helpers --net remoteattempt_default --network-alias app -p 9999:8080 -w /opt/project/ -i remoteattempt_app /usr/bin/python3 /opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiprocess --qt-support=auto --client host.docker.internal --port 59084 --file /opt/project/main.py

f09e92c865b5053f717c8b6a9642ad04b681e7b2dc153a7881c515b16cc69e62

exit code: 0

podman start -a remoteattempt_app_1

Could not connect to host.docker.internal: 59084

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 463, in start_client

    s.connect((host, port))

socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Could not connect to host.docker.internal: 59084

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 2199, in main

    debugger.connect(host, port)

File "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 670, in connect

    s = start_client(host, port)

File "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 463, in start_client

    s.connect((host, port))

socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

exit code: 1

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Screenshots
[image: python interpreter]
[image: Docker Tools]
[image: Container log]
[image: Run/Debug config]

EDIT 3/29/24
Note that this all "just works" when using Docker (not podman).  So, I have surmised that this is a problem with podman.